# qmake error when trying to build qwbfs

Tags: qt, makefile, make

I'm trying to install [qwbfs](http://code.google.com/p/qwbfs/) application but when i enter the command : make
i get this:

```
tools.c:8:25: fatal error: openssl/md5.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [../build/release/obj/unix/tools.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/speedox/qwbfsmanager-1.2.2-src/libwbfs'
make: *** [sub-libwbfs-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

can you please tell me where is the problem.
thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the Qt 4 development packages. Particularly, that program is in the `libqt4-dev` package.

Comment: i tried the synaptic pm and installed the search results for libqt4-dev but there is another error now (see the first post i edited it)

Comment: You will need to install all the necessary development packages for the dependencies of the program you are trying to build. You may need to consult the documentation, source, or upstream for the program you wish to compile, to determine that list.

Answer (score 1):

Please reports problems in the area requested by the author -
There is [Google issues tracker](http://code.google.com/p/qwbfs/issues/list) and [Google discuss group](http://groups.google.com/group/qwbfs-discuss)
For your problem it will be fixed quickly if you read the Readme's of [qwbfs](http://code.google.com/p/qwbfs/source/browse/trunk/README) and [libfresh](https://github.com/pasnox/fresh/blob/master/README).

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your help,
the needed packages are:

```
apt-get install gcc
apt-get install libncurses5-dev
apt-get install libssl-dev
apt-get install openssl
apt-get install libnet1-dev (Note here it is libnet"number1" not letter "l"
apt-get install libpcap0.8-dev
```

with sudo